# Capture data going through named pipe

Tags: pipe, fifo

Is there a practical and easy way to capture data going through a named pipe? I've tried wireshark, but it only accepts a specific data format. I've also tried cat, but I get mixed results.

Thank you

Comment: Have you thought of `tee` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out how to read the data using shell scripts as described here:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash

```
while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
        if [[ "$line" == 'quit' ]]; then
            break
        fi
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up two named pipes and connect them with

```
tee -a pipe.log < pipe1 > pipe2
```

Then have the first app write to `pipe1` and the second read from `pipe2`.

Alternatively you could connect them with

```
tee pipe2  < pipe1
```

To have the data piped to your stdout.